# Posting message on wall from facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, extjs, facebook-wall

I am developing an application in Extjs (Sencha) where I want to post a message to Facebook user's wall. This application is a Facebook application so it must post a message to user's wall through Facebook Application. It is just like normal message from a FB application but it is not working on my side. Below image will show how I want the message. Also there is a condition for posting this message there is no need of user login.This message application send send at anytime even when other user is loged in.

I think below points will help to understand my situation.
1) User A will login in application he can see other Application users (Friends or not friends)
2) He want to send message to user B who is not a Friend of User A
---Here user A's message will be send as Application post to User B's wall Just like below image

[image: This is demo image which will show how I want the message]

Comment: how it's not working? Can you show the tutorials you are following?

Comment: Hoang Long thanks for reply.
I used all the code from every site & FB developer site.

Comment: Sandip: it's hard to say anything with your description here. But it's not logical to expect a user can post to wall of another non-friend user.